# reverse database information django

Tags: django, database, reverse

I am trying to get last 5 items added. I really don't know how to do this.
I tried the reverse() function . to limit the query i used [:5]

extra question: whats the request context for? i didn't understand djangodocs

model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    postit = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def timer(self):
        return self.createdat


    def who(self):
        return self.user

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.postit
```

View:

```
def chat(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            storyi = form.save(commit=False)
            storyi.user = request.user
            storyi.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/chat/')

    else:
        form=StoryForm()

    try:
        p = Topic.objects.all()[:5].reverse()

      )

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        p= "don't try it again"

    return render(request,'chat/chat.html',{'form': form, 'p':p})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If last added you mean last in list, it should be [-5:].
for example:

```
In [22]: a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
In [23]: a[:5]
Out[23]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [26]: a[-5:]
Out[26]: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What exactly are you interest in RequestContext? 
RequestContext is to return specific values in response.
Example:

```
def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    t = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'foo': 'bar'})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Here you return `'index.html'` template with rendered values `{'foo':''bar}`

UPDATE:
In your case you can use RequestContext like this:

return render(request,'chat/chat.html',{'form': form, 'p':p})

......

```
template = loader.get_template('chat/chat.html')
c=RequestContext(request, {'form': form, 'p':p})
return HttpResponse(template.render(c))
```

Comment: when using [-5:]  i am getting this error: Negative indexing is not supported.

FOr the requestContext , when and where do i need to use it? Do I need to use it here?

Comment: @nokker Try this Topic.objects.all().order_by('createdat')[:5]

Comment: It worked, but i had to do this "-createdat". Thank you very much!

Comment: @nokker I have added update about RequestContext. You are welcome.

Comment: Oh, but why are people using the requestContext? My code seems way shorter.

Comment: @nokker It could be useful when you want to use context processors. Check it here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: Thanks for everything :)